# How to fix manger name using only one table and using only 1 id

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can I get a result set which contains a column with the manager's name, like this:

```
+----+---------+-----------+
| id | empname |managername|
+----+---------+-----------+
|  1 | sandeep |   NULL    |        
|  2 | xyz     |   sandeep |
|  3 | abc     |   xyz     |         
+----+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: You're going to need a column which says whether or not an employee is a manager.

Comment: Perhaps you read your notes from your last lessons first...

Comment: my requirement is 1st employee manager id is null,and 2nd employee manager is 1st employee and 3rd employee manager is 2nd employee lyk this @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: In the second (resulting) view we can see that 'abc' is a manager of 'abc'. According to 1st view, it is 'xyz' who is a manager of 'abc'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a query like this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.empname, tt.id As managerid, tt.empname AS managername
FROM (
    SELECT t1.id, t1.empname, MAX(t2.id) AS nextId
    FROM yourTable t1
    LEFT JOIN yourTable t2 ON t1.id > t2.id
    GROUP BY t1.id, t1.empname) t
LEFT JOIN yourTable tt ON t.nextId = tt.id
ORDER BY t.id;
```

That handles a `LAG()` function.

If you use SQL Server 2012+; you can simply use this:

```
SELECT id, empname, 
    LAG(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) As managerid, LAG(empname) OVER (ORDER BY id) As managername
FROM yourTable;
```

And also in older versions:

```
;WITH t AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn
    FROM yourTable) 
SELECT t.id, t.empname, tt.id, tt.empname
FROM t
LEFT JOIN t tt ON t.rn = tt.rn + 1;
```

Comment: tq,,i need this only

Comment: In some databases like PostgreSQL, SQL Server and etc. there are some simpler ways, But as you didn't tag your question with them I give this only ;).

Comment: k,,,fyn taged nowcheck it

Comment: i think it is  big,,is there any simple way

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
select a.id , a.empname ,a.managerid,b.empname as managername 
from employee a
left outer join employee b on b.id=a.managerid
```

Comment: No man not lyk this,i have only 1 id i.e Empid,,i have only 3 columns  empid and empname and manager name

Comment: @sandeep Now check query